# How to find the type of a value that has been implicitly converted?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to pull the following code out of a class into a trait for reuse:

```
import org.slf4j.{LoggerFactory, Logger}
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration


object UserProfileFixtures {
  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserProfileFixtures.getClass)

  val table = UserProfileQueries.query

  // todo: Create a trait for all this
  def createSchema(db: Database) = {

    logger.info("Creating schema for the UserProfiles table")
    Await.result(db.run((table.schema).create), Duration.Inf)
    logger.info("UserProfiles table schema created")
  }
}
```

The problem is that `table` is implicitly converted to something which adds the `schema` property. If I just lift-and-shift the above, the implicit conversion on `table` doesn't happen, and the compiler can't find the `schema` property.

How can I find out what type I should give `table` in the following trait?

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration


trait FixtureHelper {

  val logger: Logger
  val data: Seq
  val table: TableQuery[_]     // this type is wrong...

  def createSchema(db: Database) = {

    logger.info("Creating schema")
    // compiler can't resolve `schema` in the line below
    Await.result(db.run(table.schema.create), Duration.Inf)
    logger.info("Schema created")
  }
}
```

I'm using slick 3.0 BTW, not that that should make a difference. I want to know how to find out the type of a value after it's been implicitly converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use structural types to get the resulting implicit class:

```
scala> implicit class RchStr(s: String) { def v = 0 }
defined class RchStr

scala> implicitly[{def v: Int}]("aaa")
res5: AnyRef{def v: Int} = RchStr@3ab71d5e //"RchStr" is implicitly inferred type here

scala> implicitly[{def v: Any}]("aaa")
res6: AnyRef{def v: Any} = RchStr@2de743a3 // you may not know type of `v` - just specify `Any` then

scala> implicitly[{def z: Any}]("aaa") //there is no implicit conversions to something which has `z` member
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("aaa")
 required: AnyRef{def z: Any}
              implicitly[{def z: Any}]("aaa")
                                       ^
```

Here I required some implicit conversion for anything with method `{def v: Int}`. In your specific case it should be something like:

```
println(implicitly[{def schema: Any}](table).getClass())
```

If you need to find out the initial type of `table` you may just use `table.getClass` or inspect the scaladoc for implicitly inferred `table`'s type for implicit conversions.

Also IntelliJ IDEA shows you (Cntrl + mouse hover) inferred type explicitly. You may also need to checkout some supertypes of the inferred type.

Also may be helpful: [Showing inferred types of Scala expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230185/showing-inferred-types-of-scala-expressions), [Inferred type in a Scala program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189316/inferred-type-in-a-scala-program)

This will give you type tag for exact type which can be implicitly converted to something with `schema`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def typeOf[T](x:T)( implicit tag: TypeTag[T], conversion: T => {def schema: Any} ) = tag
println(typeOf(table))
```

Comment: OK it gives me: slick.profile.RelationalProfile$TableQueryExtensionMethods. Sorry to be a complete amateur, but what type do I need to give 'table' for this to work? I've tried replacing the $ sign with a dot, and using square brackets, but Intellij still won't resolve it.

Comment: OK so I know I have to make `table` of type `slick.profile.RelationalProfile$TableQueryExtensionMethods`, but what's the syntax? I don't seem to be able to reference the nested class.

Comment: Oh I need to replace $ with #.

Comment: ... and now it can't find the `create` property of table.schema :-( I'll start a new question.